# angular-ui-sortable with bootstrap grid

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui-sortable

I have a list of items with different column widths in bootstrap.
The items are getting displayed correctly in their respective columns.
I am trying to add a sorting feature to this items using angular-ui-sortable.
The items are getting dragged but return to their original position after I drop them. Also if I select any item and try to drag it, the item moves to the top left corner.

```
<div ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="itemList">
   <div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
      <div class="col-sm-{{item.cols}}">
        <div class="box">{{item.cols}}</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can find the [full Plunker example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fE1vMc9zgovLgzJD2xwq?p=preview)

Comment: what are the css and js you have included more instead of this example js and css??

Comment: Additional css and js files included can be found in index.html

Comment: try to comment out and check.keep only example js and css.

Comment: css included are : bootstrap, style.css

Comment: js included are: jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap, angular, angular-ui-sortable

Comment: comment out other css,js then demo.

Comment: I am not sure how that would work. I think all are required dependencies. Could you please explain why you think commenting other css, js would work?

Comment: bootstrap js  may conflicts with angularjs so.

Comment: Tried removing bootstrap js. Still the same behavior.

Comment: you only have to include jquery-2.1.4.js,jquery-ui.js,1.4.8/angular.js,sortable.js,script.js. remove all other js.

Comment: That is exactly what I have. Total 5 js scripts in the same order that you mentioned

Comment: Demo works perfectly so other things make conflict in this.